# Filtering data from a device to a raspberry pi

Tags: python, list, types

Quick question for data types in Python.  I am fairly new to python so I am not sure which option to go with.

I have data coming from a device (text and int) which I am to store, manipulate into a nice fashion and then display it onto a raspberry pi display.  The device code was written in C, but I chose python for its simplicity with the RPi.

Question is what data type would be a good option to go with here? List[]? Dictionary (so I could have a meaningful key name to define the data)? namedtuple()?

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: If you describe what the data looks like, we can give better answers (e.g. is it many variables, like temperature and humidity measured over a long period of time, or just a counter, etc) The nature of the data helps, raw types like (text, int) is not very informative

Comment: bakkal- I will try to describe the process. I send the device(battery pack) a text string of what data I want from it such as temperature, state of charge, extremes of information, current etc. I send it all these messages get all of this data back (in text, int format) and I want to then filter it nicely for the pi to display. This is all done down a USB line. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I send the device(battery pack) a text string of what data I want from
>   it such as temperature, state of charge, extremes of information,
>   current etc.

I see! So you are sending *requests* to your device,
assuming this is home/learning project,
you might want to create a very simple "protocol"

## Request message

so e.g. you can define a message format like below:

```
{
    'action': 'get',
    'resource': 'temperature',
    'params': {'rooms': [1,2], period_min=60} # last 60 min, for room 1 and 2
}
```

So in the above I have defined a format that comes with `(action, resource, params)` tuple, all of it is a simple dictionary with those 3 keys

As you can see this simple dictionary object can describe a very good range of uses!

To send the request to your device you'll have to *serialize* it, i.e. convert it to a stream of characters to be reconstructed on the device as a Python dictionary. JSON and YAML are easily compatible with that message format, but there are many more equally useable formats.

## Storage

I Assume you're talking about storage in a device to display the message

### pickle

If it's just a single result, maybe just pickling it to a file will do, this is very simple as it basically just saves and then later on loads the Python object from a file

### sqlite

If you're storing a big dataset like recording measurements, then perhaps a database/datastore is required. You can get `sqlite` running easily on your devices to work as a DB backend for your Python code

SQLite data types, https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

pickle: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

sqlite3: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am already using 'import serial' to send the data out and get it back.  I am just looking for a good way to store the data.  I will look further into your method!

Comment: SQlite will be something I must implement later, but what data type does SQlite take?  This is kind of what I'm getting at if I want to easily store to that database will it understand tuple dictionary type? or will it understand just a list? or an Array?